# SQL Server Table Index To big

Tags: sql-server, index

I have a table that has approximately 450k records
here is the structure of it

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reviews](
[ReviewID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AuthorName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AuthorURL] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Rating] [int] NULL,
[Comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[UTCCreatedDate] [date] NULL,
[IsImported] [bit] NULL,
[ListingID] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Reviews] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ReviewID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reviews]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Reviews_Listings] FOREIGN KEY([ListingID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Listings] ([ListingID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reviews] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Reviews_Listings]
GO
```

Now when I look at the index sizes of all my tables (via posted tsql) here http://basitaalishan.com/2012/07/06/find-the-size-of-index-in-sql-server/

The review table has a massive 446264K (approximately 450MB) index on just the primary key.

What are my options on reducing/eliminating this as I am not sure how useful this is as this is just a related table (child)

Comment: The 450MB on the primary key (which is CLUSTERED) is the entire table. So that's about 1k a record which is not surprising with so many nvarchar columns, including a MAX one.

Comment: Is 450MB that big of a deal?

Comment: @jnk thanks i thought that was just the index size, I changed my column to varchar(4096) which was a result of me  select max(len(comment)) from reviews and return was 4095.  Now the size of the table is 225mb

Comment: @JohnM it was considering it made up 30% of my database so I was looking for ways to reduce it

Comment: The clustered index IS THE TABLE.  In a phone book, the index is on LastName, FirstName but the entire book (table) is ordered that way.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not the primary key.  It is a misunderstanding of what a clustered index is.  If you look at your structure you will see that the primary key is clustered.  This is the default and fairly normal but is not always the case so it pays to check.

The clustered index is basically the table itself.  The data pages of the clustered index are the data pages of the table.  So your 450mb for the primary key is mostly the data of the table itself.  At 446264K that makes it about 1k per row which is not unreasonable depending on the amount of data in the AuthorURL and Comment columns.

Comment: Yep i misunderstood what I was looking at, thanks all for the help

Comment: What are my options if the field may contain unicode and maximum length of my field is 4095? nvarchar only goes upto 4000 so is there anything else I can use other than nvarchar(max)?

Comment: @Zoinky think about putting that into another table?

Comment: nvarchar(max) is your only option if you want a unicode field that can go past 4000.  Remember though it only takes up as much space as the data that's in it.